# Service authentication using Twitter Oauth

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, sinatra, soa

I have a website that uses Twitter Oauth for Authentication. I plan to break out the site to use a service approach where the website communicates with a backend via JSON. Since the front end is responsible for going out to Twitter to validate the account and as a result, sets the session, I'm trying to figure out how to still have the path and use a service backend with something simple like Sinatra.

Problem is that there's no password to authenticate against for the API backend, just twitter key and secret. What's the best way for the website to authenticate the request to the API back end having come back from Twitter login?

Answer (score 0):

You could exchange the Twitter OAuth creds for an API session with your Sinatra back-end. So the Sinatra API knows the Twitter user associated with the API session.

You can obtain the initial API session key by authenticating with the back-end using an API key (a shared secret, really). This assumes that your front-end API client is itself a server-side application rather than client-side - you don't state which.